# Error with react hook: Component's values keep re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

It's me again and I still having trouble with react-hook with redux

I'm trying to use the useMemo method to get the data collection from firestore.

The UserDetailed component will be called after user logined and clicked in a Dropdown's item called "Profile" in SignedIn component.

in App.jsx, I declared the path for using UserDetailed Component:

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <Fragment>
        <ModalManager />  
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
        </Switch>
        <Route path='/(.+)' render={() => (
            <Fragment>
                // NavBar component is placed here
                <NavBar />
                <Container className="main">
                    <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/blogs' component={BlogDashboard} />
                  <Route path='/blogs/:id' component={BlogDetailedPage} />
                  // Route for UserDetailed component is placed here
                  <Route path='/profile/:id' component={UserDetailed}/>      
                    </Switch>
                </Container>
            </Fragment>)} 
        />
    </Fragment>
);
};
export default App;
```

The SignedIn is placed in a Navigation Bar:

in NavBar.jsx:

```
const NavBar = ({history}) => {
const firebase = useFirebase();
const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth, []);

const handleLogout = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
        history.push('/');
    });
};

const authenticated = auth.isLoaded && !auth.isEmpty;

return (
    <Menu fixed='top'>
        <Container>
            <Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to='/blogs' name="Blogs"/>
            {authenticated ? 
                (<SignedIn signOut={handleLogout} />) : 
                (<SignedOut />)
            }
             </Container>
         </Menu>
)
}
```

in SignedIn.jsx:

```
const SignedIn = ({signOut}) => {
const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth, []);

return (
 <Menu.Item position='right'>
  <Image avatar spaced='right' src={profile.photoURL} />
  <Dropdown text="My profile">
    <Dropdown.Menu>
       // this is where the SignedIn component is called:
      <Dropdown.Item as={Link} to={`/profile/${auth.uid}`} text='Profile'/> 
      <Dropdown.Item onClick={signOut} text='Sign Out'/>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
 </Menu.Item>
);
};
```

in UserDetailed.jsx:

```
const UserDetailed = ({match: {params}}) => {
    const firebase = useFirebase();
    const isCurrentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid === params.id;
    console.log(isCurrentUser);  

    const getUserProfile= useMemo(() => ({
       collection: 'users',
       doc: params.id,
       storeAs: 'userProfile'
    }), [params.id]);

    console.log(getUserProfile);

useFirestoreConnect(getUserProfile); //get datas from here

return (
    <div></div>
);
};
export default UserDetailed;
```

The "isCurrentUser" and "getUserProfile" did return the values that I expected, but It just keep re-rendering until It reach the max depth and throw the "Maximum update depth exceeded" error.
Why is this happening ?

Comment: Can you show all the custom hooks that you wrote and what is `userProfileQuery`?

Comment: @ChandraKumar, It was my mistake when editing the post, It must be getUserProfile, I updated my post

Comment: @ChandraKumar, sorry for the late response but I updated the route for this component . Turns out I have problem with the whole component not just with useMemo method.